# Firebase cloud functions database trigger is not run correctly sometime

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have write the following code which is running good. But recently  I find that the trigger does not update the internal value sometimes. Is there anything wrong in my code ? I have attached the logs and codes in the follows.

Log : the internal flag of request 0411193257728 does not updated after 30 sec.

```
7:33:01.008 pm
publishRequest
call constructor
7:33:01.777 pm
publishRequest
process the request ref = 0411193257728
7:33:02.096 pm
publishRequest
Function execution took 30038 ms, finished with status: 'ok'
7:33:02.098 pm
publishRequest
request 0411193231315 updated !
7:33:31.786 pm
publishRequest
Function execution took 31465 ms, finished with status: 'ok'
7:36:30.592 pm
publishRequest
Function execution started
7:36:30.603 pm
publishRequest
process the request ref = 0411193630508
7:37:00.607 pm
publishRequest
Function execution took 30016 ms, finished with status: 'ok'
7:37:02.295 pm
publishRequest
request 0411193630508 updated !
```

**code**

```
exports.publishRequest= functions.database.ref("Request/{requestID}")
.onCreate( async (snap, context) =>{  
    console.log("process the request ref = " + context.params.requestID);
    await sleep(30000);   
    snap.ref.child("internal").set(false)
            .then((value) =>{ console.log("request " + context.params.requestID + " updated !")} )
            .catch((error) => console.error(error));
    return;
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`set()` is asynchronous and returns a promise.  Since you are using async/await syntax, you should use that to make sure the function waits until the write is complete.  If you don't want for the promise to resolve, Cloud Functions might terminate and clean up async work before it's complete.

```
exports.publishRequest = functions.database.ref("Request/{requestID}")
.onCreate( async (snap, context) =>{  
    console.log("process the request ref = " + context.params.requestID);
    await sleep(30000);   
    try {
        await snap.ref.child("internal").set(false)
        console.log("request " + context.params.requestID + " updated !");
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
})
```

Actually, you should probably not even try to trap the error - just let the function error out if the write fails for some rason.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.  I like your firecast video. i